# include of non-modular header error in a swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods-1.0.1

We have a swift framework in which we have created a custom modulemap to import CardIO.h from CardIO library which is a static framework.

But after doing that we are getting this error: "include of non-modular header inside framework module". any tips on how to solve this ?